# Standard deviations and significance values

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, standard-deviation, outliers

I was wondering if data 2 SD from the mean is deleted as outliers, is it possible there after to report 0.01 significance values? Thanks!

Comment: You're not classifying data as outliers on that basis alone, are you? Why do you think this would affect the matter of reporting significance?

Comment: Well I'm analyzing another paper and that is the only method they have identified for deleting outliers. I was just thinking if you delete values after two sigmas, how can you get confidence levels for 0.01. Though I guess without the outliers you get a new mean and distribution. I think I just figured it out - Thank you!

Comment: Basically, removing outliers means changing the underlying population about which you can do inference. So if they e.g. remove people not aged between 18 and 70 based on the Mean+-2 SD rule and then provide a 99% c.i. of 40-44 for mean age, this just means that with 99% confidence, the average age in your population of people within 18 and 70 is somewhere between 40 and 44. There is no direct link between the 2SD rule and 0.01 significance.

Comment: Significance of what test, exactly?

Comment: A side note: as far as I understand, the SD is computed using all observations. If you consider the data (0,0,0,1000) with a mean of 250 and an SD of 500, the point 1000 is not classified as an outlier, because it highly influences the SD itself. Including the outliers to estimate the standard deviation and then using this standard deviation to find outliers seems to be a somehow circular reasoning.

Comment: Glen_b : two-way and three-way ANOVA. binkyhorse - that's one of the main criticisms that I'll try to state for the paper, thanks!

Comment: @Victoria Unless the "outliers" are due to data entry error or something like that, they are the most interesting part of the data (whatever caused them seems to be important, and a confound others should watch out for). Whether two groups are exactly the same or not (what a significance test tells you) is the least interesting aspect of the analysis in nearly all circumstances. If this is the case, the paper should be rejected as unfit for publication.

Comment: Victoria, if you want to get the attention of someone when you reply to them, put @ in front of their name, like @Glen_b -- or they won't know you've replied. Exceptions are the poster of a question sees all comments, and the poster of an answer sees all comments under their answer (so you don't need to @ in those cases).

Comment: anova? Then two sd's of what from the mean of what? Is this done on the unconditional response (i.e. without considering the independent variables)?? If it's what it sounds like, it's a disastrous idea.

Answer (score 2):

Removing outliers does not change the ability to get significant differences:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- c(rnorm(50,0,1), 10)
y <- rnorm(50,5,1)
t.test(x,y) #t = -18.44, p < 0.0001
xnoout <- x[x < 8]
t.test(xnoout,y) # t = 27.91, p < .00001
```

But removing all data that is more than 2SD from the mean as outliers is not a good idea.

Comment: Actually, I think you've demonstrated that removing outliers can increase the ability to get significant mean differences :) I suppose it should in general if it decreases the standard error of the mean. IOU +1 in 13 hours (SE has my voting finger on cooldown), but FWIW, it's not clear that this is a question of mean differences. An NHST of a correlation might behave differently due to inclusion/exclusion of outliers. E.g., with `i=c(rnorm(50),10);j=rnorm(51,5);inoout=i[i<8];cor(i,j);cor(inoout,j[1:50])` you'll sometimes get stronger correlations with the outlier, and sometimes without.

Comment: Sure, removing outliers *could* remove significance.  And I took a guess at t-tests.

Comment: Usually a good guess, and always a good place to start! Just felt like debating with myself I guess. :)

Comment: @PeterFlom If there are outliers due to some cause other than researcher error, the population distribution is probably not normal.

Comment: @Livid That's true, but so? Or are you saying that t-test is a bad example?

Comment: @PeterFlom For example, sample from a 50/50 mixture of two normals N(0,1) and N(1,1) and drop outliers without replacement (defined as >2 SD from each sample mean), I see ~10% results when p<0.05 with n=50. Also the effect sizes when you do get a significant result will be inflated. I actually suspect this type of thing is a common occurrence in biological studies.

Comment: OK, that is a different example. Removing outliers can have a variety of effects.

Comment: @PeterFlom Yes, it appears to depend on sample size, the distribution, and the "outlier rule". Using median absolute deviation is worse. It can get scary. Try dropping 5xMAD from N(0,1) N(8,1) ~25% of the results are p<0.05 for N=5-15. If someone runs the experiment with n=5, then adds another batch of 5 to each group if not significant until n=15, 45% of the time they will get p<0.05. Say they are also looking at 3 different outcomes like that, 85% of the time they will get significance! That is an extreme example, but it shows how dangerous these practices are.